# Is there an example where for a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ which converge to $z \not= 0$, but $\{arg (z_n)\}_{n \geq 0}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Is there an example where for a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ which
>   converge to $z \not= 0$, but $\{arg (z_n)\}_{n \geq 0}$ diverge?

I thought this is true for a sequence like $\{\frac{1}{n}+i\}_{n \geq 0}$, but $\arg (\frac{1}{n}) = \arctan(n)$ can't diverge, because the function $\arctan()$ is a bound function. Since $\arg()$ is defined in function of $\arctan()$, the only possibilities that $\arg()$ doesn't converge is if 
right limit is different from the left limit.

What kind of sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ could I take here?

Comment: I didn't see the $z_n \to z \ne 0$. hence if $arg(z)$ is not at the discontinuity point of $arg$  it is easy to show that it is impossible, because $z \ne 0 \implies \ln\displaystyle\frac{z_n }{z} \to 0$. an other interesting question would be to ask when $\lim_{x \to \infty} arg(f(x))$ exists with $f$ being continuous, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = z \ne 0$ and $arg(f(x))$ is also continuous (phase unwrapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you define your $\arg$ with value in $]-\pi,\pi].$

Then take a discrete convergent spiral with center on the line $]-\infty,0]$.

**Edit** : Easier idea. Consider the sequence $z_n = -1 + (-1)^n \frac{i}{n}.$ This sequence converges to $-1$ and $arg(z_n)$ does not converge.